# Automapper Queryable Extensions Map to Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to map the Address property of the view model from the address property of the database table class using `.ProjectTo<POHeader, POHeaderViewModel()`, but getting the error:
`The entity or complex type 'Address' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`

I'm I just doing this incorrectly syntactically or is this not possible and I need to flatten my view model to include each address field or have it inherit from `Address` and map the fields explicitly?

Database Table:

```
public partial class POHeader
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FacilityId{ get; set; }
    public int? ShipToAddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual Facility Facility { get; set; }
    public virtual Address ShipToAddress { get; set; }
}
```

View Model

```
public class POHeaderViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ShipToAddressId { get; set; }

    public Address ShipToAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Map

```
CreateMap<POHeader, POHeaderViewModel>(MemberList.Destination)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShipToAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Address != null
        ? 
        new Address()
        {
            CompanyName = source.Address.CompanyName,
            Address1 = source.Address.Address1,
            Address2 = source.Address.Address2,
            City = source.Address.City,
            StateOrRegionCode = source.Address.StateOrRegionCode,
            PostalCode = source.Address.PostalCode,
            CountryCode = source.Address.CountryCode,
            PhoneNumber = source.Address.PhoneNumber,
        }
        : new Address() {
            CompanyName = source.Facility.Company.CompanyName,
            Address1 = source.Facility.Address1,
            Address2 = source.Facility.Address2,
            City = source.Facility.City,
            StateOrRegionCode = source.Facility.State,
            PostalCode = source.Facility.PostalCode,
            CountryCode = "US",
            PhoneNumber = source.Facility.PhoneNumber,
        }))
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried adding a `Facility` to `Address` map:

```
CreateMap<Facility, Address>(MemberList.Destination)
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyName, option => option.MapFrom(entity => 
                entity.Company != null 
                ? entity.Company.CompanyName
                : "")
            )
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, option =>option.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, option => option.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Address3, option => option.Ignore())      
            .ForMember(dest => dest.StateOrRegionCode, option => option.MapFrom(entity => entity.State))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryCode, option => option.MapFrom(entity => entity.Country))
```

Then changed the `POHeaderViewModel` map to the below...but got the error: `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'Address' and 'Facility'`

```
CreateMap<POHeader, POHeaderViewModel>(MemberList.Destination)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShipToAddress, c => c.MapFrom(m => 
        m.Address != null 
        ? m.Address
        : m.Facility
        ))
```

Comment: What you're doing here is manual mapping. You need an AddressViewModel and a map to it from Address/Facility. You might want to start with an LINQ query to better understand what's possible. And then rewrite that with ProjectTo.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to do that when mapping to Address is conditional on the value in POHeader.AddressId. Any further directions?

Comment: The way you're already doing it, with a check inside the MapFrom expression.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu sorry, I guess I'm dense, because I still don't know how to do this. I tried creating a `Facility` To `Address` map and then in this POHeader map, I had `.ForMember(dest => dest.ShipToAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Address != null ? source.Address : source.Facility))` but this gives the error that `Facility` is not of type `Address`.

Comment: @chad-richardson I tried to reconstruct your mapping scenario and it just works fine for me. It could be because I did some simplifications with properties of missing models. So if you could add the code for other models you use, that is `Address`, `Facility` and `Company` that would be great.